# Business visa for Germany

Tags: visas, uk, germany

I am a businessman from Lahore, Pakistan. I am going to apply for a business visa for Germany. I got a refusal for a UK tourism visa from the British High Commission 4 months ago. Now do I have to tell them about my refusal or submit the refusal letter with the documents to apply for a visa at the German embassy?

Answer (score 3):

If the application form, or immigration official, asks about previous refusals, always answer honestly. If they catch you lying or omitting important information they are extremely likely to refuse you.